# Google Drive API v3 - Convert doc to pdf

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, pdf-generation

I am trying to convert a Google Doc file to pdf.

I tried to use the `files.copy` method with the `mimeType` in the resource, as suggested in their "Migrate to Google Drive v3" [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/migration). But it doesn't work: it makes a simple copy without converting. It looks as if the mimeType is never taken into account...

```
gapi.client.drive.files.copy({
  name: 'My new PDF',
  fileId: sourceId,
  parents: [destinationId],
  mimeType: 'application/pdf'
})
```

(Note: I'm trying to do this in the browser)

I also tried with 'text/plain', but didn't change either.

**UPDATE**:

It looks like converting during a copy method can only convert to a Google-specific mimeType (document, sheets, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it's rather [gapi.client.drive.files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/export):

```
gapi.client.drive.files.export({fileId: sourceId, mimeType: "application/pdf"});
```

Comment: Yes, but for my use case, I want to put the newly converted file in Drive. The `export` method will make me download it. I would need to re-upload it and that's not efficient.

Comment: @Errorname think one cannot even do that in the web GUI. printing to PDF document is an export; conversion is only for uploads.

Comment: I guess I thought it would be possible. i'll go with the export method then

Comment: @Errorname you could deploy nodeJS to Cloud Functions and make it an HTTP trigger, which takes the fileId and destination filename; as a simple micro-service.